# flask-sqlalchemy, one-many relationship, foreign key changes into NULL

Tags: python, mysql, foreign-keys, one-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have user table and album table etc.. and user-album have one-many relationship.

But when a user associates with one or more albums, the foreign key excluding the latest one from the album table changes null. [This is the case that user_uid=1 have 3 albums and user_uid=2 have 1 album.(BUT foreign key having user_uid=1 is only just one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMGry.png) And this problem also occurs everywhere having one-many relationship. Here is my code..

```
class User(Base):
__tablename__ = 'user'

uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
username = Column(String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)
email = Column(String(35), unique=True, nullable=False)
salted_password = Column(String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
profile_pic = Column(String(100))
authorization = Column(Boolean)
expiry = Column(DATETIME)
fcm_token = Column(String(45))
created_at = Column(DATETIME)
albums = relationship('Album')
notifications = relationship('Notification')
like_photo = relationship('Photo', secondary=like_photo)
follow_album = relationship('Album', secondary=follow_album)
followed = relationship('User',
                           secondary=followers,
                           primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == uid),
                           secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == uid),
                           backref=backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
                           lazy='dynamic')
comment_photo = relationship('Photo', secondary=comment)




class Album(Base):
__tablename__ = 'album'

aid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
title = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
created_at = Column(DATETIME)
user_uid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.uid'))
photos = relationship('Photo')
album_tags = relationship('Album_tag')
```

And I updated album table like below..

```
u = User.query.filter(User.uid == session['uid']).first()
u.albums = [Album(title=request.json['title'], created_at=datetime.utcnow())]               
db_session.add(u) 
db_session.commit()
```

I don't know why..

Comment: Can u post code related to how you post data to your tables?, How u update user and album tables?

Comment: (First I find user 'u' who is in session) u.albums = [Album(title=request.json['title'], created_at=datetime.utcnow())]; db_session.add(u); db_session.commit();

Comment: I think like this you are overriding the list of albums, better do it the other way around, create Album, then assign its Album.user_uid = u.uid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to do it the other way around, since in your way, you are overriding user's albums list:

```
coffee_album = Album(title=request.json['title'], \
                     created_at=datetime.utcnow())
u = User.query.filter(User.uid == session['uid']).first()
coffe_album.user_uid = u.uid
db_session.add(coffee_album) 
db_session.commit()
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you.